Show that the maximum of negative binomial cannot converge to a non-degenerate distribution
Let $X \sim NegBin(m,p)$, where $m$ is a positive integer and $p \in (0,1)$.
$X$ is a random variable with $P(X=n) = {n+m-1 \choose n}(1-p)^n p^m$ for $n \geq 0$.
I want to show that as $n \to \infty$, $\frac{P(X=n)}{P(X \geq n)}$ does not converge to $0$.
I was able to write $\frac{P(X=n)}{P(X \geq n)}$ as $1/A$ with
$A = 1+\sum_{s=1}^\infty (1-p)^s \frac{(n+m+s-1) \ldots (n+m)}{(n+s) \ldots (n+1)}$
But I don't know what to do with the term $\frac{(n+m+s-1) \ldots (n+m)}{(n+s) \ldots (n+1)}$.
Thank you.

I would have expected $\frac{P(X=n)}{P(X \geq n)}$ to be an increasing function of $n$ at least when $m\ge 2$ and to converge towards $p$ as $n$ increases.  When $m=1$ you have a memoryless geometric distribution and it is a constant $p$ throughout.

@Henry that's my expectation too, just not sure how to show it. Maybe my simplified expression is wrong.

Hint: use Stolz–Cesàro theorem (case $0/0$)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P(X=n)}{P(X\ge n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P(X=n)-P(X=n+1)}{P(X=n)}$$
The RHS limit is quite straightforward to calculate.

yep, quite easily get the limit to be $p$ with this one. Thanks.
